# Would biotechnology in agriculture actually decrease biodiversity, as many people say? Does it have to?

Tags: biotechnology

I've heard the claim that because farmers would be using the same seed, you would end up with an entire crop population that could be susceptible to a disease. Like if you had a diverse population of potatoes, not many of them could become blighted, but if you have only one kind of potato on your farm and that kind is susceptible to Phytophthora infestans, then all your potatoes would become blighted.

I was wondering:

1. Is this really how it works? Like once a seed with a desired characteristic is found, is it cloned? Or would they implement the same gene into many different crops?
2. If they do clone them, why couldn't they implement the same gene into a diversity of crops? Is it too costly?
3. Could one use mutagenesis to create diversity? If the seeds are cloned, could a certain number of the seeds be modified to try to account for natural diversity?